# Displaying json from API in node

Tags: json, node.js, api

I am trying to display flickr pictures for a simple web application in node using flickr's API. My below method does not work as it hangs indefinitely and never logs any data when I go to the url. (I commented out the render to focus on the json data).

```
request = require("request"),

    app.get("/", function(req,res){
        var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=gt500&tagmode=any&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"

        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }), function(err, res, body) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            if(!err && res.statusCode == 200){
                console.log(body);
                 res.render('home');
            } else {
                console.log("status code errort");
            }
        }

        // res.render('home');
    });
```

It appears the request object is still awaiting a value here as nothing happens in the above code.

Comment: for `request` which module u are using?

Comment: I am using the request module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of passing options in `json` format to for `request` module. just pass the `url` as show below:

```
request( url , function(err, res, body) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    if(!err && res.statusCode == 200){
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        res.render('home');
    } else {
        console.log("status code errort");
    }
});
```

Comment: I originally tried that one, but it still loads indefinitely without logging anything to the console when put inside my app.get("/,...) call. My goal was to load the flickr pictures in the home page by passing them as data by calling `res.render('home',{flickrdata:body})` once I figured out why nothing will log.

Comment: It's not logging to console because content is too large try using `console.log(JSON.parse(body));` this will log the content

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!